# Entity Framework filter a query by child collection and include entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have been facing a problem in filtering out a query.
The structure is as:

```
Survey 
-- Page
----- PageLanguages
----- SurveyQuestions    
------------ QuestionsSkipLogic
------------ QuestionsDisplayLogic    
------------ Questions
------------------ QuestionVariables
```

The `Survey Table` contains a property **SurveyId**, similarly `Question Table` contains a property **MarketId**. My requirement is to filter out the data on the bases of **SurveyId** and **MarketId**.

```
var surveys = _db.Surveys.Where(x => x.SurveyId== surveyId)
                 .Include("Pages")
                 .Include("Pages.PageLanguages")
                 .Include("Pages.Questions")
                 .Include("Pages.Questions.SkipLogics")
                 .Include("Pages.Questions.DisplayLogics")
                 .Include("Pages.Questions.Question")
                 .Include("Pages.Questions.Question.Variables")
                 .ToList();
```

How to filter this query by **MarketId** too?

Comment: `db.Surveys.Where(x => (x.SurveyId == surveyId && x.MarketId == marketId))` ?

Comment: @Baksteen basically marketid is inside the questions model so you cannot get x.MarketId

Comment: Since the `MarketId` is property of a sub collection element, you need to clarify what do you mean by filtering on it. Usually it means having any element matching the filter. If that's the case, use `.Where(s => s.Pages.SelectMany(p => p.Questions).Any(q => q.MarketId == marketId))`. But note that this will filter only the `Survey`s - there is no way to apply filter on `Inlcude`s.